# JMS Service and Broker count issue

Tags: glassfish, jms, glassfish-3

Whenever I am trying to deploy my application I keep getting this Exception in the logs:

```
MQJMSRA_LB4001: start:Aborted:Unable to ping Broker within 60000 millis
```

I couldn't understand why this was happening so I checked domains/domain1/imq/logs/log.txt and this is what I found:

```
No threads are available to process a new connection on service admin. 10 threads out of a maximum of 10 threads are already in use by other connections. A minimum of 2 threads must be available to process the connection. Please either limit the # of connections or increase the imq.<service>.max_threads property. Closing the new connection. ". Count: service=5 broker=5
```

Can someone help me with understanding how to increase this count.. 
I would really appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the connection properties (max_threads) of the broker as the error message suggests. The broker configuration file is \domains\\imq\instances\imqbroker\props\config.properties.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you are using OpenMQ in `embedded` mode or not. If you are using `embedded` MQ, look for the `Thread Pools` section of your config in the admin console. One of them will have a max threads set to 10, that will be the one to increase.

It's hard to be sure since you haven't given any other detail from the logs, but that is very likely what you need to change.

[image: screenshot]